# adding new object value into existing object value over and over again

Tags: javascript, function, object

I need to write a code so that result comes out as

```
{ username: 'Cloud', 
  species: 'sheep', 
  tagline: 'You can count on me!', 
  noises: ['baahhh', 'arrgg', 'chewchewchew'], 
  friends: [{username: 'Moo', species: 'cow'...}, {username: 'Zeny', species: 'llama'...}]
}
```

but my code currently prints first as the new object added onto the existing object and when I try to add another new object onto the existing object and console.log it, it replaces the last object added and only adds the new object values.

```
{ username: 'Cloud',
  species: 'sheep',
  tagline: 'You can count on me!',
  noises: [ 'baahhh', 'arrgg', 'chewchewchew' ],
  friends: 
   { username: 'Moo',
     species: 'cow',
     tagline: 'asdf',
     noises: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
     friends: [] } }
{ username: 'Cloud',
   species: 'sheep',
   tagline: 'You can count on me!',
   noises: [ 'baahhh', 'arrgg', 'chewchewchew' ],
   friends: 
    { username: 'Zeny',
      species: 'llama',
      tagline: 'qwerty',
      noises: [ 'z', 'x', 'c' ],
      friends: [] } }
```

Here is my code so far. I only put animal2 = animal to write that it replaces it so that when adding another new object value it adds it into that object, not the original. Do I need to have a loop here in order to have this work?

```
function AnimalCreator(username, species, tagline, noises) {
  var list = { 
    username: username,
    species: species,
    tagline: tagline,
    noises: noises,
    friends: []
  };

    return list;

}

function addFriend(animal, animal2) {

    animal.friends = animal2;
    animal2 = animal;


}

var sheep = AnimalCreator('Cloud', 'sheep', 'You can count on me!', ['baahhh', 'arrgg', 'chewchewchew']);
var cow =  new AnimalCreator('Moo', 'cow', 'asdf', ['a', 'b','c']);
addFriend(sheep, cow);
console.log(sheep);
var llama = new AnimalCreator('Zeny', 'llama', 'qwerty', ['z', 'x', 'c']);
addFriend(sheep,llama);
console.log(sheep);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem looks to be in `addFriend(animal, animal2)` where you set `animal2 = animal`. What I think you are trying to do is append friends which could be done like

```
function addFriend(animal, animal2) {
    var pastFriends=animal.friends;
    pastFriends.push(animal2);
    animal.friends = pastFriends;
}
```